# Parsing json to JSONObject messes with original order

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have json that I want to parse as a JSONObject.
When I do so, it messes up the order of the json, see below.
How can I fix this?

original json:

```
{"result":
    {"headers":
         {
         "month_1":"May 2013",
         "month_2":"April 2013",
         "month_3":"March 2013",
         "month_4":"February 2013",
         "month_5":"January 2013",
         "month_6":"December 2012",
         "month_7":"November 2012"
          }
     }
}
```

After parsing to JSONObject:

```
{"result":
    {"headers":
        {
        "month_6":"December 2012",
        "month_5":"January 2013",
        "month_4":"February 2013",
        "month_3":"March 2013",
        "month_2":"April 2013",
        "month_1":"May 2013",
        "month_7":"November 2012"
        }
    }
}
```

My code:

```java
private void ProcessResponse(String response) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
}
```

Comment: How does that affect you?

Comment: Why you want to fix it? Just fetch the data using keys and do your work. :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON libraries does stick to the order of elemts within JSON obects. To get more details please follow [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/). But the code should not be tightly dependent on the order of elements within a `json object`.

Answer (score 0):

A way I can think of is, try to convert JSONObject to an arraylist, then use the code below.
All I can think of at the moment. How to convert, try to search this on google.

```
 Collections.sort("your arraylist", new Comparator<Item>() {
            public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
                return i1.getCaption().compareTo(i2.getCaption());
            }
        });
```